# How can I reverse proxy an HTTP request from PHP, including select headers

Tags: php, curl, reverse-proxy

My PHP app sometimes needs to reverse proxy some content from an upstream (legacy) HTTP backend.

I can use the Curl module to do that, which gives me fine control over the backend request headers and content (for instance to post some content) but I can't figure out how to stream the response back including the relevant response headers.

For example, my PHP app needs to post some JSON to the backend, which will generate a big zip file. How can I stream the zip file back to the client, without caching it, including the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers, which contain the file type and most importantly the file name?

If I unset `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, the backend response is streamed correctly, but without headers. If I additionally set `CURLOPT_HEADER`, the backend headers are also passed through, but then the client gets two copies of the HTTP headers (one from PHP, the other from Curl.)

On the other hand, if I set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, then I have to cache the response somewhere (in memory or in a temp file) which is sub-optimal.

Is there any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`, making sure to return the number of bytes consumed for each header, whether you output it or not.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($ch, $header) {
    if (preg_match('/^Content-(Disposition|Type):.*/', $header)) {
        header($header);
    }
    return strlen($header);
});
```